# text assign to textbox onclick hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem on jquery onclick. when onclick happen on a link text box value should fill with the some hard coded text.

ex

```
  $('#linkBase').click(function() {

         $('#txtFormula').val("txnword");

    });
```

problem is I want to repeat the "txtword" on the text box when I click on the link as "txtwordtxtwordtxtwordtxtwordtxtword" but currently I'm getting only once when click the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#linkBase').click(function() {
               $('#txtFormula').val($('#txtFormula').val() + "txnword");                 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var formula = $('#txtFormula');
formula.val(formula.val() + "txnword");
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that doesn't use jQuery for simple things like this:

```
document.querySelector('#linkBase').onclick = function()
{
    document.querySelector('#txtFormula').value += "txnword";
};
```